# Using IFS to recognise new lines when populating an array

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting, ifs

I'm having problems with the IFS environment variable. 
I am trying to create an array like so:

```
IFS=$'\n'
FILENAMES=( "$(ls -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }')" )
```

I know that when I run this line

```
$ ls -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }'
```

My output is placed in a format where each output is on seperate lines, so why does my array contain all of the output as the first index, instead of putting each line in separate indexes, the output I get is:

```
$ echo ${FILENAMES[0]}
file1.txt file2.txt
```

and the output I want is

```
$ echo ${FILENAMES[0]}
file1.txt
$ echo ${FILENAMES[1]}
file2.txt
```

I have already tried setting IFS like so:

```
IFS="
"
```

However this made no difference, and the output was still as I had originally, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you have quotes… But (no offense) this is a horrible way to achieve what you want (and it's completely broken too).

Comment: Using IFS without the quotes removes the letter n from my variable $LOC, this is not what I wanted, and when I echo $IFS after setting it like IFS='/n', I am given a new line.

Comment: I mean quotes here: `FILENAMES=( "$(ls -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }')" )`. Remove the double quotes: `FILENAMES=( $(ls -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }') )`. But this is so buggy and broken and horrible!!!

Comment: Why is it buggy and broken and horrible?

Comment: You're just making all the possible mistakes a noob would make (no offense, really!). For one, your code breaks if there are spaces in a filename (you'll only get the first part of the name). That's easy to fix, though. You're relying on the output of `ls`, and that's a dangerous assumption (other systems or `ls` versions might have a different one). You're using a pipe of `sed`, `grep` and `awk` which clearly shows that you're not aware that `awk` (or `sed`) on its own could do the job. It's completely broken because pathname expansion will be performed.